# ¿Por qué me quita los puntos el decimal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

En mi base de datos tengo el campo precio `decimal(8,2)`.

En mi modelo `public decimal? Precio { get; set; }`.

Luego si por ejemplo yo ingreso 10,10 me dice que no es un número, eso está bien, debo usar el punto y no la coma, ese no es el problema, utilizando el punto en vez de la coma me lo termina eliminando y el resultado final sería 1010, lo que ingrese menos el punto.

¿Cómo puedo evitar que suceda esto?

Comment: ¿En que gestor de base de datos estás trabajando?

Comment: estoy usando  sqlserver management studio

Comment: ¿Podrías publicar la función desde donde haces el insert?

Comment: que base de datos utilizas ? como envias el valor numerico del precio a la operacion que realizas contra la db ? podrias poner el codigo del INSERT o UPDATE que realizas. Esas Entity Framework?

Comment: @Barri debes de fijarte el collation que tiene tu base de datos por ejemplo si creaste un script o debiste colocar algo como esto.... COLLATE Modern_Spanish_CI_AI

Answer (score 0):

Mira el problema en verdad es de jquery, porque solo maneja el estilo americano donde los decimales se separan con un "."
Lo que hice fue una en el modelo use string con formato numérico y donde al momento de guardarlo cambiaba el . por , y cuando lo presentaba igual

modelo

```
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:n}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
  [Required, Display(Name = "Neto", Description = "Neto de la factura", Prompt = "Neto de la factura")]
  public string neto { get; set; }
```

la entidad si tenia formato decimal

```
  [Column("base")]
  public Decimal neto { get; set; }
```

Yo uso mapper y tengo una funcion de validacion algo así

```
       //cargos
       CreateMap<cargo, CargoModel>()
            .ForMember(m => m.neto, e => e.MapFrom(src => Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.neto.ToString(), false)))
            .ForMember(m => m.iva, e => e.MapFrom(src => Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.iva.ToString(), false)))
            .ForMember(m => m.renta, e => e.MapFrom(src => Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.renta.ToString(), false)))
            .ForMember(m => m.monto, e => e.MapFrom(src => Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.monto.ToString(), false)));
       CreateMap<CargoModel, cargo>()
            .ForMember(e => e.neto, e => e.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDecimal(Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.neto, true))))
            .ForMember(e => e.iva, e => e.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDecimal(Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.iva, true))))
            .ForMember(e => e.renta, e => e.MapFrom(src => Convert.ToDecimal(Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.renta, true))))
            .ForMember(e => e.monto, e => e.MapFrom(src => (Convert.ToDecimal(Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.neto, true)) + Convert.ToDecimal(Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.iva, true)) + Convert.ToDecimal(Validaciones.Utils.ValueEU(src.renta, true)))));
```

y funciona bien la función validación si te sirve es esta

```
  public static string ValueEU(string iMonto, bool eu)
  {
       if (eu)
            iMonto = iMonto.Remove(iMonto.Length - 3, 1).Insert(iMonto.Length - 3, ",");
       else
            iMonto = iMonto.Remove(iMonto.Length - 3, 1).Insert(iMonto.Length - 3, ".");

       return iMonto;
  }
```

Bueno a mi me soluciono el problema espero te sirva aún
saludos